# How many Antiviral definitions exist in 2017 for the linux antivirus Clamav?

Tags: antivirus, clamav, clamtk

How many virus signatures should the clamav engine have, you know some web page where it can be consulted, you can add more antiviral signatures, I find very few of them?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the most recent update on my system, over 8 million signatures are downloaded and installed into several files that are used.

```
Thu Jan 12 13:40:12 2017 -> Downloading daily-22881.cdiff [100%]
Thu Jan 12 13:40:15 2017 -> daily.cld updated (version: 22881, sigs: 1340001, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
Thu Jan 12 13:40:15 2017 -> safebrowsing.cld is up to date (version: 45447, sigs: 2444663, f-level: 63, builder: google)
Thu Jan 12 13:40:15 2017 -> bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 285, sigs: 57, f-level: 63, builder: bbaker)
Thu Jan 12 13:40:19 2017 -> Database updated (8003511 signatures) from db.us.clamav.net (IP: 69.12.162.28)
Thu Jan 12 13:40:19 2017 -> Clamd successfully notified about the update.
Thu Jan 12 13:40:19 2017 -> --------------------------------------
Thu Jan 12 14:40:19 2017 -> Received signal: wake up
Thu Jan 12 14:40:19 2017 -> ClamAV update process started at Thu Jan 12 14:40:19 2017
Thu Jan 12 14:40:19 2017 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
Thu Jan 12 14:40:19 2017 -> daily.cld is up to date (version: 22881, sigs: 1340001, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
Thu Jan 12 14:40:19 2017 -> safebrowsing.cld is up to date (version: 45447, sigs: 2444663, f-level: 63, builder: google)
Thu Jan 12 14:40:19 2017 -> bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 285, sigs: 57, f-level: 63, builder: bbaker)
Thu Jan 12 14:40:19 2017 -> --------------------------------------
```

If you want to make sure that your `freshclam` is updating at regular intervals, run the following command from a terminal window:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam
```

Step through the pages, and on the number of updates per Day, it should be set to 24 which means once per hour.  Also, these setup pages allow you to set the `freshclam` update to a daemon so that you don't have to worry about manual updates.

Comment: Hi Terrance, I have encountered the following errors when trying to update freshclam :ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).

Comment: Thanks @Terrance, You could take a look at this:Thu Jan 12 18:32:32 2017 -> --------------------------------------

Thu Jan 12 22:32:40 2017 -> bytecode.cvd is up to date (version: 285, sigs: 57, f-level: 63, builder: bbaker)
Thu Jan 12 22:32:46 2017 -> Database updated (5558848 signatures) from db.local.clamav.net (IP: 194.8.197.22)
Thu Jan 12 22:32:46 2017 -> ERROR: NotifyClamd: Can't find or parse configuration file /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
Thu Jan 12 22:32:46 2017 -> --------------------------------------

Comment: @Alberto For the NotifyClamd, run the following to configure it `sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-daemon`  Most of the default settings should be fine.  It will also create the `clamd.conf` file for you.

Comment: I have been very helpful to your answer although I still have some other problem with the configuration, it tells me that ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process.Thank you very much.

Comment: @Alberto That is because the `freshclam-daemon` has control of the updates.  In your log file updates have happened today.  As long as you see updates you are fine with it.  No need to run the `sudo freshclam` itself.